# how to remove name spaces in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, namespaces

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><DocumentCombined xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/schema/ACCO_EDI_X12_Scheduledjobs/Write_867xmlfile">
   <Header xmlns="">
      <ISADATE>
         <value-of/>
      </ISADATE>
   </Header>
</DocumentCombined>
```

here i need to remove the xmlns name spaces to the DocumentCombined element and Header elements.

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<DocumentCombined>
   <Header>
      <ISADATE>
         <value-of/>
      </ISADATE>
   </Header>
</DocumentCombined>
```

Comment: http://www.sachinhandiekar.com/2011/12/remove-namespace-using-xslt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to strip all namespaces simply use

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```